# At most one field out of n is not null

Tags: c#, algorithm, boolean-logic

I have n fields in a class. At most one of them is allowed to be set, and so I need to throw an exception if that's not the case. I know the value of n.

I can do this the obvious way:

```cs
    if (field1 != null && (field2 != null || field3 != null ||...)
        || field2 != null && (field1 != null || field3 != null ||...)
        ...)
        throw new Exception();
```

However the length of this is n^2 in the the number of fields, and I most definitely don't want to write this out for eg. 10 fields.

I've seen suggestions that recommend doing this via reflection. However, whilst that's necessary where you don't know the value of n, I can't help thinking there must be a simpler way here.

So is there a way to check if at most one of n values is not null, whilst only accessing each value once?

Comment: Count the number of null/non-null fields and compare. Or just use a collection type to hold the values (assuming they're the same type).

Comment: rethink it. use an array or another enumerable data structure. or increment a value whenever you encounter one non-null, throw as soon as count reaches two.

Comment: @dlatikay. Sometimes an array is appropriate. Sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a counter for how many fields are set.

```
int numberOfSetFields = 0;

if (field1 != null)
    numberOfSetFields++;

if (field2 != null)
    numberOfSetFields++;

if (field3 != null)
    numberOfSetFields++;

...

if (numberOfSetFields > 1)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Or, you could use a property in order to no longer check other fields if there are at least more than 1 already set

```
int numberOfSetFields = 0;
int NumberOfSetFields 
{
    get { return numberOfSetFields; }
    set 
    {
        numberOfSetFields = value;
        if (numberOfSetFields > 1)
            throw new Exception();
    }
}

if (field1 != null)
    NumberOfSetFields++;

if (field2 != null)
    NumberOfSetFields++;

if (field3 != null)
    NumberOfSetFields++;

...
```

The set method of the NumberOfSetFields property will check if there are at least 1 set fields. That way, if, let's say you have 10 fields, and the first 2 are set, then the other 8 will no longer be checked when compared to the first method I've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper method with a descriptive name that makes it more clear on the calling side what you are trying to check for, like this:

```
public static bool MoreThanOneNotNull<T>(params T[] items)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        if (items[i] is object && ++count > 1)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (MoreThanOneNotNull(field1, field2, field3, field4, ... ))
    // ...
```

Comment: I think the disadvantage of this is that it unnecessarily allocates an array, but in many contexts that's going to be a premature optimization, and it certainly is clearer than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public int NotNullToOne<T>(T val) => val is null ? 0 : 1;

if (NotNullToOne(field1) + NotNullToOne(field2) + NotNullToOne(field3) + ... > 1)
   throw new Exception();
```

NotNullToOne returns 1 if the value is not null, o if it is.

If more than one value is null, the sum of all the `NotNullToOne`s will be greater than 1, and so this will throw.

Comment: In his code in the question he checks every combination of fields, ie. "9 ok fields + 1 null" then "8 ok fields + 1 null + 1 ok field", etc. This one counts the OK fields and checks.

Comment: This is linear in the number of fields, not quadratic.

Comment: This is exactly the was *Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen* mentioned in his comment to your question.

Comment: @MrSmith42
Yes it is. I happened to think of it and write this answer, whilst he wrote that comment.